# Better use two dedicated methods hooked with add_action() to different actions, or can it be twice the same method?

Tags: actions, performance

This is merely a question about what's better in terms on performance, and general (WordPress) PHP Development.

I deregister and dequeue a fewe scripts (and styles) from a WordPress website, in a Custom PHP Function, which I `add_action` like so `add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_custom_method', PHP_INT_MAX );`

In my `my_custom_method` I gather some plugin options, global post, and more data, then I run `wp_dequeue_script` and `wp_deregister_script` iterating over each script I set to be removed (plugin options), same for styles.

This works fine for all scripts and styles I wanted to remove so far.
However, there is **one** script added to `get_footer` (by a third party plugin), so when hooking into `wp_print_scripts` this one is not removed.
It is removed when I hook my method (obviously) into `get_footer`, but in this case, styles aren't removed.

So I just ended up hooking my method to both `wp_print_scripts`  and `get_footer`, which works.

My question is, is it OK to just `add_action()` the same method twice (once to `wp_print_scripts`  and once to `get_footer`), or would it be more performant if I reduce the method hooked to `get_footer` to just `wp_deregister_script` the **one** script added in `get_footer`?

Answer (score 0):

So there's 4 factors:

- Performance (Speed, resource usage)
- Convenience
- Code maintainability
- Learning the API you're using

If you don't know the performance of your function then it's impossible to answer your question, but I would guess that if it doesn't do or cause any database queries, and it's not doing operations on lots of data, then it's probably fast.

It seems like what you're doing is convenient - you have the code in one place and call it from a couple of places it's needed.

Even though it's called from two places, as the code is in one place that's quite maintainable. If you want to change what it does in future you don't have two places and need to figure out where to put changes, you just change this one function and you know the effect will happen.

You could do this a different way but it sounds like you're saying that this would involve a lot more time to learn the interface you're using (i.e. WP script queueing orders) and this might not have a benefit for you.

So, on balance if it's a fast function there's no reason not to do this and it's not bad design due to maintainability.